# Class that can inherit from two different classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance

So I am working on an implementation of a Dynamic Decision Network (DDN) class.
This DDN is a type of Bayesian Network (BN) with some additional functionality.

However, I also defined a Quantum Bayesian Network (QBN), that uses quantum computing to perform inference. Its implementation is very similar to the BN class, I only change one of the BN methods to perform quantum computations instead (the query method) and add some other methods just to help perform these computations.

I want the DDN class to be able to inherit from the BN class if one wants to perform the computations classically, and inherit from the QBN class if one wants to perform the computations in a quantum manner.

The code looks something like this:

```
class BN:
   ...
   def query(self, ...):
       ...

class QBN(BN):
   ...
   def query(self, ...):
      # Modified query method
      ...

class DDN(???):
   ...
```

Am I structuring the hierarchy wrong in some way? How can I reconcile this?

Comment: It sounds like you want two different `DDN` classes, say, `class DDN1(BN):` and `class DDN2(QBN):`?

Comment: Perhaps the DDN functionality could be written as a mixin class.  You'd create two concrete classes from it: `class BN_DDN(BN, DDNMixin):` and `class QBN_DDN(QBN, DDNMixin)`; the bodies of these two classes would probably just be a `pass` statement.

Comment: @quamrana yes, that is a possibility for sure, but that would imply repeating all of the code within the DDN class besides the inheritance class (the question marks in the code I provide above)

Comment: Ok, so there's another way of having the single class but inheriting from others on demand ... see my answer.

Comment: If `DDN` is something that can use either kind of Bayesian network, then it should probably not encapsulate details specific to either kind. `DDN` is a standalone class whose instance can be use by either a `bn_query` or `qbn_query` method/function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the class into a factory function:

```py
def make_DDN(Base):
    class DDN(Base):
       def other_methods(self):
           ...

    return DDN
```

Now you can make new classes:

`DDN1 = make_DDN(BN)`

etc

Answer (score 0):

The working field of your program is unclear to me, and it is unclear what objects and their methods should be able to do, so this is a suggestion, not an answer. But it's too big for a comment.

```
class BN:

    def method(self):
        return self.data*2

class QBN(BN):

    def method(self,classic=False):
        if classic:
            return super().method()
        return self.data*3

class DDN(QBN):

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This seems like a neat solution!
The only thing that kind of itches me is that I'd like it to be impossible to use the classical method within the QBN class. Solving this would be neat, but for practical purposes this seems to do the trick!